# Is it Possible to Write a Script that Can Open All Links on One Page, but in a New Window then Run a Script?

Tags: javascript

I am new here. I am curious: I want to run a script that opens all links on a site map that opens in a new window but runs the script below:

Is it possible through Vanilla JS in the browser?

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll('a');
let linkArray = [];

for(i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let pageLink = x[i].href;
    if(pageLink.match(/www2/g)) {
    linkArray.push(pageLink + "<br>")
    }
 }
 
 displayLinks = () => {
 let w = window.open("");
 w.document.write(linkArray.join(''));
 }
 
 displayLinks();

</script>
```

Comment: Yes try this one in loop. `document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click();` and `target="_blank"` in all your `a` tag

Comment: I think the builtin popup blocker in Chrome/Firefox/<insert browser here> prevents more than one window/tab being opened per user interaction

Answer (score 1):

You could add `target="_blank"` to your  tags,
then this should work:

```
 const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

        links.forEach(link =>{
            window.open(`${link.getAttribute('href')}`);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open a link in a new window/tab.

```js
for (let anchor of document.querySelectorAll('a')) {
  window.open(anchor.getAttribute('href'), '_blank');
}
```